# jQuery ".triggerHandler()" vs. ".trigger()" when multiple elements are selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

The jQuery ".triggerHandler()" mechanism, unlike ".trigger()", only operates on the first element referenced by the jQuery object for which it's called.  In other words,

```
$('.all-over-the-page').triggerHandler("readjust");
```

will only call the "readjust" handler for the first element with class "all-over-the-page", even if there are many elements on the page with that class.  The ".trigger()" method, on the other hand, would affect all of them.

I realize that I can use ".each()" to get around this (or simply write my own substitute that does that for me), but is there some rationale for why the two are different in this respect?  It kind-of makes no sense to me.  (I understand of course that it almost certainly can't be changed now.)

*edit* to clarify:

It's probably easier to understand why I'm scratching my head over this if I provide a context in the style of code I've actually got.  When I put together code for various "widget" features on a page, that often involves event handlers. A good example is a form of some sort that's got some fields whose relevance is controlled by a checkbox, or radio button, or selector. A common instance of that is the "Shipping Address" checkbox that shows up on a zillion e-commerce sites: if the checkbox is checked, the shipping address is disabled and the billing address is used.

Now consider that some *other* code may, for its own reasons that are totally independent of the checkbox-control widget, actually do things to the form that may include updating checkbox settings programmatically. In that case, that other widget code may want to use "triggerHandler()" to tell any widgets, "hey I've updated some stuff, so you might want to re-check the current status and adjust if necessary."

Thus, if ".triggerHandler()" would operate on all selected elements, I could use:

```
 $theForm.find('input, select, textarea').triggerHandler('change');
```

and all those handlers could run and do whatever they need.  As I said, it's easy enough to write:

```
 $theForm.find('input, select, textarea').each(function() {
   $(this).triggerHandler('change');
 });
```

Comment: I'm not sure what specifically you're trying to do here.  Can you give a little more context of what you are attempting to resolve?

Comment: Updated with some more explanatory material.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> *"...is there some rationale for why the two are different in this respect?"*

I think the idea is that `triggerHandler()` is meant to be a way of invoking the function you as a handler as though it was any other function.

As such, they made `triggerHandler()` so that the function is only invoked once, it returns the actual return value of the function, and it doesn't affect the DOM with bubbling or default behaviors.

Of course the function may break if they changed the `this` value to something other than a DOM element, so they just use the first element matched.

If you're wanting to simply use your function, then I'd probably just keep a reference to it and invoke it directly, or as the argument to `.each()`.

```
$('.element').each( handler_func );
```

...as long as you don't need the `event` object.

---

**EDIT:** Or if you want the values returned from the invocation, use `.map()` instead:

```
var return_values = $('.element').map( handler_func );
```

---

**EDIT:** With respect to the example provided in the updated question, a good solution may be to take advantage of the *extraParameters* capability of the [`trigger()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method so that you can tell the handler to `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()`.

```
$('.elememts').bind( 'click', function( e, was_code_triggered ) {

    if( was_code_triggered ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
    // your code
});


// ...


$('.elememts').trigger( 'click', true ); // pass "true" to let handler know
                                         //    it wasn't a DOM event
```

*From the `.trigger()` docs:*

> "Note the difference between the extra parameters we're passing here and the eventData parameter to the `.bind()` method. Both are mechanisms for passing information to an event handler, but *the extraParameters argument to `.trigger()` allows information to be determined at the time the event is triggered*, while the eventData argument to `.bind()` requires the information to be already computed at the time the handler is bound."

Comment: Well OK, but it strikes me as kind-of weird to write event handlers that expect to be able to return a value.  And I'm OK with not doing the default behaviors; that's really problematic with "click" on checkboxes (for example).

Comment: @Pointy: Yes it is weird, unless you have a function that is useful as a standalone function, as well as a handler. I'd think that case would be rare. Was it the disabled bubbling that you were after in using `triggerHandler`? EDIT: Just noticed the update to your question. Reading...

Comment: @Pointy: I see what you're after. Yeah, if you don't want `.each()` (whether passing a function directly, or using `triggerHandler()` within), you may want to consider using the *extraParameters* capability of `.trigger()` to pass a flag that will tell the handler that it should `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()`.

Comment: oh durr that's an awesome idea :-) -- could even write a function to transform a handler into one that knows how to do that!

Comment: @Pointy: Good idea to write a function to automate it. I updated my answer to include the suggestion from my comment.