# keypress handler canceling the event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

I have the following code

```
 jQuery('#parent').on('keypress', '.textbox', function(e) {
    var btn = jQuery(this).closest('tr').find('.btn');
    if (btn.length) {
        btn.triggerHandler('click');
    }
});
```

This code is a delegated keypress handler which is listening to the event of textboxes having class value ".textbox".
The handler finds the button with class ".btn" & calls its click handler which has an ajax call in it.

Problem is this seems to prevent the event from completing i.e if the value in box is "2" & I type in a "3",the handler executes but the value in the box remains to be "2" instead of a "23".

It works normal when I comment out the btn triggerHandler statement.

Ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Use `keyup` instead of `keypress`

Comment: maybe you can use    btn.trigger("click")

Comment: @Grommy its the same for `.trigger`,`triggerHandler` & `.click()`.

Comment: @Developer107 I will use that probably but was wondering why this is happening?lapse of concept or what?

Comment: .trigger and triggerHander, aren't the same, you can look it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530987/jquery-triggerhandler-vs-trigger-when-multiple-elements-are-selected

Comment: @Grommy I mean this behavior is same here for all 3

Comment: @techie_28 It might be because `keyup` event completes the key default action while `keypress` must be getting interrupted by the `trigger`. Refer this - http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html

Comment: does your button click cause a page reload/refresh or redraw of textfield?

Comment: @benchpresser it has an ajax call which brings some HTML & appends to a container on the page but no reload/refresh though.

Comment: @Developer107 seems like that

Comment: @Developer107 I think the answer to this is event not getting completed due to trigger of an event of different button i.e `tn.triggerHandler('click')`..could you please post this as an answer & I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `keyup` instead of `keypress`. As in your script you have triggered another event.

```
jQuery('#parent').on('keyup', '.textbox', function(e) {
   var btn = jQuery(this).closest('tr').find('.btn');
   if (btn.length) {
     btn.triggerHandler('click');
   }
});
```

`keypress` gets interrupted by `triggerHandler` and hence doesn't allow the default action of key press to occur. While `keyup` will perform default action first, then listen to handler.

Comment: need to know more about the event behaviors.. I expected both of them to work the same.

Comment: Still cant figure out why does `keyup` get disturbed but `keypress` does..what would be the case if it was `keydown`, `mouseleave` or some other event?

Comment: Did you try using `trigger` instead of `triggerHandler`? See this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/3772559/4719761 `triggerHandler` prevents event chaining

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to keyup function.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("input").keyup(function(){
var rs= $(this).val();
  alert(rs);
        $("input").css("background-color", "pink");
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Enter your value: <input type="text">
```

Comment: I wanted to know why does keypress is getting canceled but keyup doesnt?

Comment: Keypress fire only when you press a any key and keyup fire when the user releases a key on the keyboard

Comment: I understand that but it is not about firing.Keypress & Keyup both of them are fired here but Keypress is not getting completed. i.e the value typed is not getting shown in the textbox.

Comment: You need to keyup event to get whole textbox value as you mention in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use 'onchange' insted of 'keypress' or 'keyup'

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").onchange(function(){
  var rs= $(this).val();
  alert(rs);
  $("input").css("background-color", "pink");
  });
});
```

Comment: my question was why keypress doesnt complete but the keyup does?

Comment: keypress works when you keydown it raise an event before even the value is not enter in the text field till then, but keyup raise the event after the value enter in the text field. but if you want to write a string or a word keup raise event in each letter keyup and onchange event raise after entering the whole value when you change .

Comment: yes this is correct somewhat... but why is Keypress canceled at all in my case?there should be a point of its completion where the character should have been inserted in the input field.